# ValueError: `run` not supported when there is not exactly one output key. Got ['answer', 'sources', 'source_documents']

Tags: py-langchain

I am trying to combine an agent and a chain for a chatbot, but I am having issues integrating those two.

```py
def get_api_agent():
    with open(configs.openapi_specs_filename) as openapi_file:
        raw_api_spec = yaml.load(openapi_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    api_spec = reduce_openapi_spec(raw_api_spec)
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "x-client-authorization": configs.api_jwt,
    }
    requests_wrapper = RequestsWrapper(headers=headers)
    llm = get_llm(temperature=0.3)
    agent = planner.create_openapi_agent(api_spec, requests_wrapper, llm)
    return agent

def get_retrieval_chain() -> RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain:
    return RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
        llm=get_llm(),
        retriever=get_retriever(),
        return_source_documents=True,
        verbose=False
    )

def ask(question: Question):
    """Answer a question from the user."""
    retrieval_chain = get_retrieval_chain()
    question_str = question.question.strip()
    
    tools = [
        Tool.from_function(
            func=get_api_agent().run,
            name="API Search",
            description="Useful for obtaining data from endpoints",
            ),
        Tool.from_function(
            func=retrieval_chain.run,
            name="API Search",
            description="Useful when questioning about the business and its goals",
        ),
    ]
    agent = initialize_agent(tools, get_llm(), agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True)
    prepared_question = get_retrieval_chain_template().format(question=question_str)
    answer = agent.run(question=prepared_question, input=question_str, return_only_outputs=True)
    return answer_postprocessor(answer=answer, question=question_str)
```

When I run a prompt (`ask()` method), I get this error:
`` ValueError: `run` not supported when there is not exactly one output key. Got ['answer', 'sources', 'source_documents']. ``

The error is triggered when the agent is ran:
`answer = agent.run(question=prepared_question, input=question_str, return_only_outputs=True)`